# "link with editor" for FormEditor

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am looking for a solution of "link with editor" but for FormEditor instead of ViewPart as described in http://murygin.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/link-eclipse-view-to-editor/

I try to do similar. But the "link with editor" does not fire any action.

Thanks for help!

Comment: So are you trying to link between two editors (a FormEditor and some other editor)?

Comment: No, I am trying to link between editors and the navigator explorer (tree viewer). It looks like the behavior of the package explorer in eclipse. The selection in package explorer should be updated in depend on which editor is activated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I could use "Navigator Link Helper":

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_navigator_linkHelper.html

Hier is my code in plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
   ...
   <viewerContentBinding ...>
      <includes>
         <contentExtension pattern="my.ui.navigator.linkHelper.myExplorer"/>
      </includes>
   </viewerContentBinding>
   ...
</extension>
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.linkHelper">
   <linkHelper
             class="my.ui.navigator.MyExplorerLinkHelper"
             id="my.ui.navigator.linkHelper.myExplorer">
      <selectionEnablement>
     <or>
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
        <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
         </or>
      </selectionEnablement>
      <editorInputEnablement>
     <or>
        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
        <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
         </or>
      </editorInputEnablement>
   </linkHelper>
</extension>
```

I implemented the class:

```
public class MyExplorerLinkHelper implements ILinkHelper {
    @Override
    public IStructuredSelection findSelection(IEditorInput anInput) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void activateEditor(IWorkbenchPage aPage, IStructuredSelection aSelection) {
        ...
    }
}
```