# Force Link With Editor to be activated by default in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, rcp

I am trying to get the Eclipse force activate Link With Editor option by default . The solution doesn't necessarily need to be programmatically , but it would be good. So , I could use an .epf setting too or any other option.

Till now , I found this link : ["link with editor" for FormEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002461/link-with-editor-for-formeditor)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no preference for this setting which is persisted in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` (as `<sharedElements ... elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer" ...> ... <persistedState key="memento" value="...CommonNavigator.LINKING_ENABLED=&quot;0&quot;..."/>` or `...=&quot;1&quot;..."/>`).

Programmatically, the linking enablement can be set in the class [`org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer`](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/navigator/resources/ProjectExplorer.html) via the method [`setLinkingEnabled`](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/navigator/CommonNavigator.html#setLinkingEnabled-boolean-).