# Eclipse Plugin: Link MulitPageEditorPart with Navigator

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In an Eclipse-Plugin, I have an implementation of a `MultiPageEditorPart` and it is associated with a file-extension - let's call it `f`.

When I click on a file `f` in the standard Package Explorer the Editor is opend. This works fine so far.

But what is not working, is linking this Editor with the Package Explorer. Let's say someone has several open Editors and one of them is the custom `MultiPageEditorPart`. If the custom Editor becomes selected via the tabs (not the Package Explorer) the corresponding file in the Package Explorer should be selected / marked.

Following the example in ["link with editor" for FormEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002461/link-with-editor-for-formeditor) I tried to achive this using an `ILinkHelper` and the Extension Point `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.LinkHelper`, but it is never called.

How is the `ILinkHelper` used together with a `MultiPageEditorPart`?

PS: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: ILinkHelper is for a view you define using the Common Navigator framework - Package Explorer doesn't use this.

Comment: Ok, that explains why nothing happens. Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Package Explorer seems to look at the IEditorInput of the active editor and tries to find an ICompilationUnit or IFile to show from that. See `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart` `editorActivated` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MulitpageEditorPart` (and other Editors) have an `IEditorInput` which owns a Method

```
<T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter)
```

If this Method is called with `IResource.class` or `IFile.class` it should return the IResource that is the source for the current Editor. This is then used by Eclipse to link the Editor with the View (Package Explorer).

Like this:

```
<T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter) {
   if (IResource.class.isAssignableFrom(adapter) {
       return (T) myFile;
   }
}
```